# Find maximum covered elements without block by obstacles in path

Tags: algorithm, matrix, graph, dynamic-programming

Given MXN matrix where matrix elements are either "." or "*". Where . is representing road and * is representing block or wall. Person can move adjacent forward, down and diagonally, we need to find maximum "." covered by person without blocked by wall. [Example(in image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iz6c5.png)

Can you please suggest me efficient algorithm to approach this problem?

Comment: I think the problem is that you can get endless path by looping. Do you allow user to walk on the same element multiple times?

Comment: User can choose any path but he can't pass the wall. So there can be multiple path but he needs to choose cover maximum "." without passing any block.

Comment: Just gave you a script example.

Comment: @MathieuBour your algorithm is giving me wrong answer. I tried for my Example(link given in question), it is giving me 80 but answer is 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill 
Take the biggest flood you can do.

1. You go through your matrix and find a '.'
2. Do a flood from that point. The amount of elements you flood the area you always compare it with the maximum you already found. To make this easy you can flood with a letter or a number or whatever you want but not with '.'. What you add instead of '.' consider it as a wall or a '*' so you don't try to flood that area again and again.
3. Continue to go through the matrix and try to find the next '.'. All the previous '.' where flooded so you won't consider the same area twice.
4. Redo 2 until you can't find any more '.'. The maximum will contain your answer.
5. When you have the answer you can go back in the Matrix and you already know the letter or number you flooded the area with the maximum result so you can print the biggest area.

Comment: Yeah. It looks like Flood_fill but in flood_fill, you have some starting point but this one doesn't have any starting point.

Comment: @abhi2244 You choose any . and do a flood and replace . with *. The amount of * you add it's your area. Next step is to find the next . and that will be your second flood and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the exact path or only the number of cases?

Edit: here a smallp Python script which creates a random matrix and count the number of cases in each zone defined by your "walls".

```
import numpy as np

matrix = np.random.randint(2, size=(10, 10))
print(matrix)
M, N = matrix.shape

walked = []
zonesCount = []


def pathCount(x, y):
    if x < 0 or y < 0 or x >= M or y >= N:
        return 0
    if matrix[x, y] == 1:  # I replaced * by 1 and . by 0 for easier generation
        return 0
    if (x, y) in walked:
        return 0

    walked.append((x, y))

    count = 1

    for i in [x - 1, x, x + 1]:
        for j in [y - 1, y, y + 1]:
            if (i, j) != (x, y):
                count += pathCount(i, j)

    return count

for x in range(M):
    for y in range(N):
        if not (x, y) in walked:
            zonesCount.append(pathCount(x, y))

print('Max zone count :', max(zonesCount))
```

And here is the result:

```
[[0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0]
 [1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0]]
Max zone count : 50
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I modified the problem. I need to find maximum "." covered by person. He can choose any path. Please have a look at example you can able to understand.